# HTML5 API Javascript filesystem

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I understood studying the filesystem api files are written to a specific directory(temporary or persistent), I wonder if it is possible to write to a accessible directory thing as "c: \ files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.  This has been covered *many* times before here. I explained more fully in my reply to [JS Filesystem API: accessing JS FileEntry's on local system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288795/js-filesystem-api-accessing-js-fileentrys-on-local-system/18372519#18372519).

If you want a tutorial of the File System API, try [Exploring the FileSystem APIs on html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec is not being considered by other browsers. For now, the API is Chrome-specific and it's unlikely to be implemented by other browsers and is no longer being standardized with the W3C.

Answer (score 0):

No. File storage is restricted to a sandbox. It can be `temporary` or `persistent` storage.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/